# Visualizing a DICOM file of multiple frames in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dicom

I generated this brain tumor via TumorSim and converted it from .mha to .dcm using the gdcm2vtk tool.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/70gwje0a8pb42tf/T1Gad.dcm

I want to visualize it now in Matlab 2012a, I tried this, following the ankle demo (which is based on a single frame dicom file):

```
 info = dicominfo('T1Gad.dcm');
   image_data = dicomread('T1Gad.dcm');

   imtool(image_data,'DisplayRange',[]);
```

I get the following errors:

```
 Error using imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData (line 117)
  Unsupported dimension.

  Error in imageDisplayValidateParams (line 31)
  common_args.CData = validateCData(common_args.CData,image_type);

  Error in imtool/addImageToImtool (line 323)
         common_args = imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);

  Error in imtool (line 270)
            addImageToImtool(varargin{:});

  Error in mostrarDicom (line 12)
  imtool(image_data,'DisplayRange',[]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `info` is a poor choice of name because it overwrites matlab's `info`. 
Second, and to the point, `image_data` is a 4-D matrix. To see a slice you can try:

```
n=40 ; %slice number
imshow(image_data(:,:,n), [])
```

Comment: Interestingly, the variable name 'info' is suggested in the MATLAB reference: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/dicominfo.html